# Laravel Eloquent OrderBy with a belongsTo on model Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is there anyway to dynamically OrderBy a belongsTo in Laravel? Or can this only work on join only? I would like  to keep it as clean as possible that's why I use belongsTo.

This is my query, the problem I'm having is I don't know how to query the relational table.

```
$users = User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
->search(trim($this->search))
->orderBy($this->column,$this->order)
->paginate($this->size);
```

My $columns variable

```
$columns = collect(['username'=>'Username',
                            'email'=>'Email'
                            ]);
```

I want to add `name`, `code`, and `id` from the `companies` table to the options I have in the `$columns` variable.

This is gives me an error of `column not found` when I try to order by `company.name`
[image]

This is how I display  it on the frontend because I have `belongsTo` in the modell

```
<td>{{$user->company->id}}</td>
<td>{{$user->company->name}}</td>
<td>{{$user->company->code}}</td>
<td>{{$user->username}}</td>
<td>{{$user->email}}</td>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish and what problem you're having? It's not very clear at the moment. Your first code block is an Eloquent relationship method, seemingly unrelated to the second block which is a Query Builder statement, and then the third is a variable that isn't used in either of them.

Comment: I think you looking for dot notation, didn't found docs exactly on this, but `->orderBy('company.name', $this->order)`

Comment: @miken32 I have a one table with `User` and `Company` the only columns that I can orderBy is only the username and email from the `User` but I can't orderBy by the columns of `Company` `name`, `code` nor `id` it errors me out if I use dot notation `column not found`

Comment: You need to choose either working with Eloquent or working with Query Builder. You are working with Query Builder, so relationships have nothing to do with this, you are working directly with database structures. You probably don't have a database table named `company`. Try `companies.name` instead.

Comment: Not working @miken32 it still says column not  found.

Comment: Well, is it a database column?

Comment: Yes @miken32 but I can only `OrderBy` by `Username` and `Email` from the `User` table, I want to also have the option to `OrderBy` by `Company ID`, `Company Name` and `Company Code` from `Company` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the joins, maybe try

```
$users = User::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
    ->leftJoin('company', 'company.id', '=', 'users.company_id')
    ->search(trim($this->search))
    ->orderBy($this->column,$this->order)
    ->paginate($this->size);
```

Now you have company.name in the querie to order by.